# How can I stop WSUS server from reverting back to default IIS WSUS Administration SSL settings?

Tags: ssl, iis, wsus

After, configuring my WSUS to use SSL it either says connection error or reverts back to http. I have a week working on this and I implemented anything that might be the probable solution.

This is the first error I get:

*"WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.ServerSync.ServerSyncCompressionProxy.GetWebResponse(WebRequest webRequest)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.ServerSyncWebServices.ServerSync.ServerSyncProxy.GetAuthConfig()
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.ServerSync.ServerSyncLib.InternetGetServerAuthConfig(ServerSyncProxy proxy, WebServiceCommunicationHelper webServiceHelper)
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.ServerSync.ServerSyncLib.A"*

Okay fine, so I would proceed to do every appropriate fix there is which includes;

1. Creating a certificate.
2. Changing the SSL settings in the IIS manager wizard under WSUS administration.
3. Changing values in the WSUS pool.
4. `configuressl domain.server.root`.
5. Restarting the wsusservice.
6. open command prompt run as administrator and execute iisreset command.
7. open services.msc and restart WSUS Service.

After is restart and open the wsus wizard I get the http "WebException: The underlying..." error again
and when I run `wsusutil.exe configuressl` again instead of it giving me an https with port number 8531 I get http with port 8530. Please help.

Comment: How are you creating the certificate? Where are you getting it from?

Comment: it is a self signed certificate that i created. Is there something wrong doing it that way

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/deploy/2-configure-wsus#232-configure-the-wsus-servers-iis-web-server-to-use-ssl-for-some-connections

Comment: @yatso1 see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a self-signed certificate, nobody is going to trust it by default.

This includes the WSUS server itself, which will refuse to use it; this seems to be the source of your error, which specifically mentions an untrusted certificate.

If you want to use a self-signed certificate you'll need to take additional steps to make it trusted, by importing it into the (machine) trusted certificate store; this need to be done on both the WSUS server ***and*** all WSUS clients.

You really should use a proper certificate for this; if you don't have an internal certification authority, it's probably time to set it up.

Comment: thank you @massimo

Comment: But can you explain why my IIS SSL settings under WSUS administration revert back to default after I configure them?

Comment: I don't know, but the fact that WSUS doesn't like the certificate is very likely related.